# pick video using ionic 3 native camera plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

```
this.camera.getPicture({
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.VIDEO,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    }).then((videoData) => {

    console.log('video data', videoData);
```

I can't send the video data to server.

The very first thing I'm struggling with here is that how is destinationType affecting the returned result because no matter what I set (either DATA_URL or File_Uri) it always returns me some url of this structure `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20180312_210545.mp4` . (FYI: I am currently testing this on android platform). I am able to preview the video by simply putting it in video src but I am unable to send this video to the server.

This is the approach that I am using to get the video file from the returned `/storage` like URL and then to send the video to server.

```
return this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(data).then((entry:FileEntry)=>{
      debugger;
      return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        entry.file((file)=>{
          let fileReader = new FileReader();
          fileReader.onloadend = ()=>{
            let blob = new Blob([fileReader.result], {type:file.type});
            resolve({blob: blob, file: file});
          };
          fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        })
      })
    })
```

Where data parameter being passed to the resolveLocalFilesystemUrl is that same url (/storage/0..) that I mentioned earlier.

But this throws an error with error code 5 & error message ENCODING_ERR

I am not passing the encoding type here on purpose as that is for image files.

**Important Note:** if I add 'file://' to the data and then pass it to `resolveLocalFilesystemUrl()` like this `this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl('file://'+data).then(())` then I am able to create file entry which I've sent to the server and server has successfully saved the video. But I wanted to use more of a cross platform approach that will work both on Android & iOS

Comment: Did you have any official solution on this? I am passing through exactly the same issue. Also, if you could post some code, it would be great to see it contextualized. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a permanent solution for this but I have used kind of a little hack to resolve this for the time being and I am using the same code (with some minor changes) posted with question above.

here are the few changes: 
`destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,`

Comment: this code returns a video blob that i append to formData which then I send to back-end 
`readVideoFileasGeneral(data) {
    if(!data.includes('file://'))
      data = 'file://' + data;
    return this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(data).then((entry: FileEntry) => {
      console.log('file entry', entry);
      // debugger;
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        entry.file((file) => {
          let fileReader = new FileReader();
          fileReader.onloadend = () => {
            let blob = new Blob([fileReader.result], {type: file.type});`

Comment: `resolve({blob: blob, file: file});
          };
          fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        });
      })
    }).catch((error) => {
      // debugger;
      console.log('video file resolve error', error);
      // this.createNewFileEntry(data);
    });`

Comment: copy and paste in some editor to indent it and see if you can make sense of it.

Comment: Can I ask you what are you using to play your videos as well? and how?

Comment: Even having installed everything, I keep getting "plugin_not_installed" when trying it in my phone (because in the web view it is not possible). I just wanted to upload and watch videos, but after 3 days trying I could not do either. I am almost giving up, please any hints are welcome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169671/discussion-between-roger-almeida-leite-and-junaid).

Answer (score 0):

Working with Android you need to correct your URL.

You should use the resolveNativePath when you choose a video from the library.

More docs you can find here:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-path/

Comment: The reason I haven't tried this is because this is Android only, how would this plugin resolve paths in case of iOS?

Comment: When using iOS you don't need to resolve the paths. You will need to check if is running on android and then correct the path. Something like this: this.platfrom.is("android").

Comment: Ok I'll definitely give it a try but can you please elaborate more on this that why android returns URI of this type (because in some cases it return URIs with 'file://' already in the URI and in which cases or version of plugins will resolveNativePath work. Basically I wanna more about the URI scheme so if you can explain more or redirect me to an article that would be great.

Comment: You will only need the correctPath when picking a photo/video from the library. (PictureSourceType === PHOTOLIBRARY). If you take a new picture or record a new video you won't need to correct the path.

Take a look at the docs:
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html

Comment: well I tried the file-path plugin and it didn't resolve the url. Used it like this `this.filePath.resolveNativePath(videoData).then(url =>{
          console.log('resolved url', url);
        });` where videoData was `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20180312_210545.mp4`

but it couldn't resolve path and threw this error dictionary `{code: 0, message: "Unable to resolve filesystem path."}`